# In Silverlight, what is the correct way to use XAML clipart?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Say I've built some clipart for my Silverlight application in XAML, or downloaded it from http://www.xamalot.com, what is the best way to use it in my app?

Is it best to create a user-control for each piece of art? Or is there a better way that I can reference it from a resource dictionary?

**Update:**

The answers provided are pretty detailed, and seem to be hinting at using this for a much larger purpose than I imagined. I really was just wanting to know the best way of consuming XAML clipart for use as (say) a button on a toolbar.

Answer (score 6):

There is a better way.

You would have an individual file for each peice of clip art but not the wrapper that the site uses, a Canvas instance directly in a resource dictionary not he best way forward.
We'll start with a `ResourceDictionary` but make it look something like this:-

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplication">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:XamlImage" x:Key="SomeImage">
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas> <!-- this the toplevel canvas from the site or your design -->
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This does two things, first it uses a `ControlTemplate` to contain the image, this is a more efficient form of storage when an image may be used multiple times such as when the image is being used as an icon.

Secondly it uses a `Viewbox` which delivers on the promise of vector based graphics, it allows the image to be scaled to a specified size.

You need to add to your project a new `Templated Custom Control` and call it `XamlImage`.  You don't need to do anything to it, it just needs to exist.

For the time being lets just add this resource dictionary to the App.Xaml (thats not likely where it will remain).

Now you can place this image in a page using:-

```
<local:XamlImage Template="{StaticResource contactnew}"  />
```

Now there are several ways forward depending on your real intent and volumes, the scenarios are to varied for me to comment exhaustively.  So taking the two extremes...

If you have just a few images you would like to pick from then you could simply create more files and add them to the `MergedDictionaries` of the app.xaml.  However the big down side is that all those image Xamls are parsed and loaded at application startup which may not be desirable.

On the other hand have you may have a large library of categorised Xaml clipart.  In which case you will want to place them in a folder structure and include a standard sized thumbnail png for each.  A Xml file to act as a catalog and then on demand load the Xaml files as needed.  In this case you can ditch the `ResourceDictionary` from the files and have the `ControlTemplate` as root element, use `XamlReader` to load the template then cache the template in your own dictionary (probably as part of a catalog implementation).

Comment: maybe I'm a bit dense: where did `contactnew` come from? Your example with how to place the image in the page isn't easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your XAML clipart objects in a database as XML, then download them on demand via a webservice. Once the downloaded XAML is present in your client you could do something like :

```
string myDownloadedXaml; // downloaded from the server
Grid myGrid; // the container in your view
myGrid.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(myDownloadedXaml));
```

Comment: +1 Correct.  Maybe store the generader element in a resource when you cant to use it multiple times, so it wouldn't need to parse it multiple times.

Comment: You need to cast the result of `Load` to `UIElement`.

Comment: @Luc: Thats a good idea but to do that the result of the downloaded Xaml needs to be a `DataTemplate`.  Then multiple instances of the image can be constructed with the `LoadContent` method of the `DataTemplate`.